# How `cv2.imwrite()` to stdout?

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to write an image to stdout. But I don't find how to make `cv2.imwrite()` support it. Is there a way to write the image to stdout?

```
    cv2.imwrite(sys.stdout, x)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, file found
```

```
    cv2.imwrite('/dev/stdout', x)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:662: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'
```

Comment: opencv is open source, maybe you can adapt the code?

Comment: with cv2.imencode you can create the encoded image in memory, but probably some file headers are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```py
import cv2
import sys
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
sys.stdout.buffer.write(cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1].tobytes())
```

A quick one-line test with `feh` installed:

```
python -c "import cv2; import sys; img = cv2.imread(\"test.jpg\"); sys.stdout.buffer.write(cv2.imencode(\".jpg\", img)[1].tobytes())" | feh -
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick.

```
print cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()
```